# How to make a diagonal UITableView in iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can you rotate a UITableViewCell for like 45 degrees to implement a TableView like this concept?
[Table View Concept](https://dribbble.com/shots/2021720-List-View)

Comment: It's just normal cell, the matter is how you handle the touch, you can check for the touch location in the cell and delegate back to forward to the above cell or current cell. If you look closely, the text wont pass the yellow line on the right, its just an eye trick

Comment: @Tj3n That's right, I didn't notice it was just an eye trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be simply a visual effect that is easy to reproduce
[image]

But it is also possible they use any framework (for example: [YBSlantedCollectionViewLayout](https://github.com/yacir/YBSlantedCollectionViewLayout))

Comment: If it's so easy to reproduce, it would be nice to let OP know how you actually did it.

Comment: @DávidPásztor The screenshot in my answer shows you how to do it. I marked a single cell on tableView

Answer (score 3):

You can use that library – 
https://github.com/yacir/YBSlantedCollectionViewLayout
or just get collectionViewLayout named 'YBSlantedCollectionViewLayout'

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIScrollView in this case. It's easier.